# DevBridge jQuery autocomplete error handling

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I cannot find documentation for that: I have a working implementation that lack proper error handling, for example when the server return **HTTP 500** or other server side errors.

According to the [docs](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) there is the function `onSearchError` but I'm not sure how I can display an error message in a similar way as the `No Results`. This is a partial snippet of the current configuration:

```
//cut
autocomplete({
  serviceUrl: 'blabla',
  paramName: 'name',
  dataType: 'json',
  deferRequestBy: 300,
  autoSelectFirst: true,
  minChars: 3,
  showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
  noSuggestionNotice: 'No Results',
  groupBy: 'label',
  onSelect(suggestion) {
      //cut
  },
  onSearchError(query, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      //todo handle error, display...something went wrong
  },
  transformResult(response) {
      //cut
  },
});
```

would be nice to somehow reuse the 'No Results' with a different text and color. Any hints?